# Tic Tac Toe Game in Assembly Language

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, x86, masm

I am trying to make Tic Tac Toe in Assembly Language How can I switch Players?
Here is my code.

```
.686 
.MODEL flat, stdcall
.STACK
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
tic BYTE "TIC TAC TOE GAME"
player BYTE "PLAYER 1 (X) : PLAYER 2 (O)"
myarray1 BYTE '1' , ' ' , '|' , ' ' , '2' , ' ' , '|' ,' ' ,'3'
myarray2 BYTE '4' , ' ' , '|' , ' ' , '5' , ' ' , '|' ,' ' ,'6'
myarray3 BYTE '7',  ' ' , '|' , ' ' , '8' , ' ' , '|' ,' ' ,'9'
choise BYTE 'X','O'
player1 BYTE "Player 1 select your position ",0
player2 BYTE "Player 2 select your position ",0
info byte ?
turn BYTE 2

.code 
main PROC
mov bl,1
mov ecx,9
L13:
push ecx        
call BOARD
call GAME
pop ecx
call clrscr         
loop L13

BOARD proc


;TO DISPLAY TIC TAC TOE GAME
mov ecx, LENGTHOF tic
mov esi,Offset tic
L0:
mov al,[esi]
call writechar
inc esi
loop l0
call crlf
call crlf


;TO DISPLAY PLAYER INFO
mov ecx,LENGTHOF player
mov esi,OFFSET player
l6:
mov al,[esi]
call writechar
inc esi
loop L6
call crlf
call crlf


;LOOP TO DISPLAY FIRST ARRAY
mov ecx,LENGTHOF myarray1
mov esi,OFFSET myarray1
L1:
mov al,[esi]
call writechar
inc esi
loop L1
call crlf

;LOOP TO DISPLAY SECOND ARRAY
mov ecx,LENGTHOF myarray2
mov esi,OFFSET myarray2
L2:
mov al,[esi]
call writechar
inc esi
loop L2
call crlf

;LOOP TO DISPLAY THIRD ARRAY
mov ecx,LENGTHOF myarray3
mov esi,OFFSET myarray3
L3:
mov al,[esi]
call writechar
inc esi
loop L3
call crlf
call crlf 

ret
BOARD endp

GAME proc
mov ecx,LENGTHOF player1
mov esi,OFFSET player1
L4:
mov al,[esi]
call writechar
inc esi
loop L4
call crlf


call readint
mov info,al

cmp al,1
je one

cmp al,2
je two

cmp al,3
je three

cmp al,4
je four

cmp al,5
je five

cmp al,6
je six

cmp al,7
je seven

cmp al,8
je eight

cmp al,9
je nine

one:
mov al,choise
xchg al,[myarray1]
ret

two:
mov al,choise
xchg al,[myarray1+4]
ret

three:
mov al,choise
xchg al,[myarray1+8]
ret

four:
mov al,choise
xchg al,[myarray2]
ret

five:
mov al,choise
xchg al,[myarray2+4]
ret

six:
mov al,choise
xchg al,[myarray2+8]
ret

seven:
mov al,choise
xchg al,[myarray3]
ret

eight:
mov al,choise
xchg al,[myarray3+4]
ret

nine:
mov al,choise
xchg al,[myarray3+8]
ret


GAME endp

exit
main endp
end main
```

Comment: Any way you want to?  It is your code, after all...

Comment: Your code is too long for most people to want to read.  If you described in English how your program is designed, and exactly how the new feature you want to add is supposed to work, it might not be a bad question.  But this is just an uncommented mess of inefficient code.

Comment: Usually in programming you try to generalize things into universal formulas, so you can write only small code implementing the general formula, and configure it by data to do the special task at runtime. In your case one of the possible configurations is having some kind of "currentPlayer" variable - affecting if current player will create X or O mark, win/lose check, score display, etc... The content of such variable can be anything you design, my first three ideas would be: `0`/`1`, `1`/`2` or `'X'`/`'O'`.

Comment: To alternate between two values you can use if-else code, or single `xor` like `xor al,23` to flip `'X'` to `'O'` and back (`0x4F xor 0x17 = 0x58` and `0x58 xor 0x17 = 0x4F`). ... for the 0/1 alternation there is other common idiom: `flipped = 1 - current;` ... (works for any 0/x alternation). The 1/2 can be achieved by (3-current) ... The thing is, that you should think for a while, what you want to achieve, and how you can generalize it. Your code is full of hardcoded ugly things, not demonstrating such thinking process going on...

Comment: BTW, if you already have Irvine32 library included, try to use it somewhat more? Like http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/source/irvinelib/writestring.htm ... check the library API to see what is available for you, to save you some more work. (The `player1` string has even nul terminator already included, yet you print it by `writeChar`, with the zero byte being outputted too (sort of bug in your current code)) ... maybe you should try to start second version from scratch, and see if you can do much better, writing it in more general/logical way, to prepare for next functionality (win check).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> .code 
> main PROC
> mov bl,1
> mov ecx,9
> L13:
> push ecx        
> call BOARD
> call GAME
> pop ecx
> call clrscr         
> loop L13
> ```

A hint to the solution to your player switching problem is already in your main code! Notice the `mov bl, 1` instruction that for the moment is totally unnecessary in your program. You can use the `BX` register to represent the current player. Easiest is `BX=0` for player 1, and `BX=1` for player 2.

On each iteration of the *main* loop you must toggle the value in `BX`, easy enough using `xor bx, 1`.

```
    xor     bx, bx   ;Sets BX=0, so player 1 starts
    mov     ecx, 9
L13:
    push    ecx
    call    BOARD
    call    GAME
    pop     ecx
    call    clrscr
    xor     bx, 1    ;This switches players, 0 becomes 1 and 1 becomes 0
    loop    L13
```

In the *GAME* procedure you need to

- display a personalized prompt. You no longer need the *Player2* message.

  ```
  GAME proc
      mov     ecx, LENGTHOF player1
      mov     esi, OFFSET player1
      lea     ax, ["1" + bx]
      mov     [esi + 7], al     ;Modifies message to show "1" or "2"
  L4:
      mov     al, [esi]
      call    writechar
      inc     esi
      loop    L4
      call    crlf
  ```
- select the right character ("X" for player 1 or "O" for player 2) on 9 different occasions.
  Everywhere you wrote `mov al, choise`, you now need `mov al, [choise + bx]`.